# Using emmeans with GAM Model: Testing Group Differences on Specific Days

Tags: time-series, multiple-comparisons, mgcv, lsmeans

I'm analyzing data from an experiment involving 3 different groups that were observed over a period of 120 days, with data collected every 5 days. I fit a GAM to capture the temporal dynamics and I also need to test for differences on specific days, namely days 50 and 60.

I'm using emmeans, and I would really appreciate it if you could review my approach and check if it was appropriate.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
library(emmeans)

# Generate data
x <- seq(-20, 100, 5)
set.seed(2)
y <- list(
   y1 = 50 + 0.09 * x^2 - 0.0009 * x^3,
   y2 = 50 + 0.08 * x^2 - 0.0008 * x^3,
   y3 = 70 + 0.05 * x^2 - 0.0005 * x^3
)
n_groups <- 3
size <- 5
DF <- data.frame(X = rep(x, size * n_groups),
                   G = factor(rep(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = length(x)), size)))
DF$Y <- rnorm(nrow(DF), mean = rep(unlist(y), size), sd = 30)

# Create plot
ggplot(DF, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = G, fill = G)) +
  stat_smooth(method = gam, formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 4))
```

[image]

```
# Fit GAM model
GAM <- gam(Y ~ s(X, by = G, k = 4), data = DF)
summary(GAM)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Y ~ s(X, by = G, k = 4)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  111.012      1.677   66.18   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(X):GA 2.991  3.000 91.13  <2e-16 ***
s(X):GB 2.987  3.000 68.36  <2e-16 ***
s(X):GC 2.952  2.998 18.32  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.587   Deviance explained = 59.7%
GCV = 1083.8  Scale est. = 1055.1    n = 375

# Calculate and compare estimated marginal means
EMM <- emmeans(GAM, ~ G | X, at = list(X = c(50, 60)))
EMM
X = 50:
 G emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    166 4.36 365      157      175
 B    162 4.35 365      153      170
 C    139 4.33 365      130      147

X = 60:
 G emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    184 4.92 365      175      194
 B    176 4.92 365      166      185
 C    145 4.87 365      135      154

Confidence level used: 0.95 
pairs(EMM)
X = 50:
 contrast estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 A - B        4.30 5.69 365   0.756  0.7303
 A - C       27.07 5.67 365   4.777  <.0001
 B - C       22.77 5.66 365   4.020  0.0002

X = 60:
 contrast estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 A - B        8.85 6.54 365   1.352  0.3673
 A - C       39.63 6.51 365   6.089  <.0001
 B - C       30.79 6.51 365   4.733  <.0001

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Comment: Yes, your analysis seems fine. This is not much of an answer so I write a comment instead. Note that the p-value adjustment is applied separately to each X, ie. two adjustments for three pairs of comparisons. This is reasonable if you pre-specified the hypotheses to test at X = 50 and X = 60 before looking at the data & doing the analysis.

Comment: Thank you @dipetkov. Yes, I am aware that the p value adjustment was made for each day separately. Do you believe this is a better approach than treating the day as categorical? I think it has more statistical power.

Comment: I agree. There are 25 time points in the simulated dataset. Think of the degrees of freedom it will take to fit the model `y ~ group * factor(x)`. And in any case, why did you collect data for x < 50 and x > 60 if your domain knowledge doesn't indicate that those extra observations are useful to estimate the comparisons at x = 50 and x = 60. A smooth non-linear relationship with time is a better approach (unless perhaps when are only a small number of time points). And you can extrapolate to time points within the observed range of time but on which no measurements were collected.